# How to run pause and stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

My task:

1. Run `setInterval` loop when I hover the current block, for example #main
2. When I hover on some children element of #main, `setInterval` has to be paused
3. After when I leave children element of #main, and return my mouse focus back to #main, `setTimeOut` should run again. here is screen http://joxi.ru/L215V3qh65weW2

---

My code:

```
let num = 0;
var timer = function() { // auto click
    { num >= $(`.the_wrap_graf`).children().length-1 ? num = 0 : num++ }
    $(`.year-wrap:eq(${num}) .q`).click()
}

var timerID = null // name of interval

$('.the_wrap_feed').hover(function (ev) { // hover run loop #main
    timerID = setInterval(timer, 3000);
}, function (ev) { // mouseleave kill loop
    clearInterval(timerID)
})

$(`.q`).mouseenter(function(e) { // kill loop when hover square
    clearInterval(timerID)
})
```

If I add callback to $(`.q`), it breaks down. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't pause a timer. But, you can stop it with `clearInterval(timerReference)` and then start a new one.

Comment: *When I hover on some children element of #main,* Yeah, but you would still be technically hovering over `#main` when you are hovering over a child of `#main`.

Comment: *"here is screen http://joxi.ru/L215V3qh65weW2"* Please don't use off-site live demo sites; instead, put your runnable [mcve] **here**, on-site, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). That makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Yes, I did It like this $(`.q`).mouseenter(function(e) {hover square
    clearInterval(timerID)
},function(e) {})

Comment: Yes, I did it, when I started it like this      $(`.q`).mouseenter(function(e) { // kill loop when hover square
        clearInterval(timerID)
    }, function(e) {
        timerID = setInterval(timer, 3000);
    })    setInterval ran twice

Comment: Need a working example or else it cannot be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause an interval timer. You can only cancel it and start a new one.

Re the requirement, I think I'd probably use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (which you're already doing, using `hover`) and track whether the cursor is in `#main` or a child:

```js
var timer = 0;
var timerValue = 0;
var inMain = 0;
var inChild = 0;

function showTimer() {
  $("#timer").text(
    timer ? "Running: " + timerValue : "Not running"
  );
}

function updateTimer() {
  if (inMain && !inChild) {
    if (!timer) {
      timer = setInterval(tick, 100);
    }
  } else {
    if (timer) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = 0;
    }
  }
}

function tick() {
  ++timerValue;
  showTimer();
}

showTimer();

$("#main")
  .hover(
    function() {
      ++inMain;
      updateTimer();
    },
    function() {
    --inMain;
    updateTimer();
    }
  );
$("#main .child")
  .hover(
    function() {
      ++inChild;
      updateTimer();
    },
    function() {
      --inChild;
      updateTimer();
    }
  );
```

```css
#main {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 8px;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<div>
  Not in main
  <div id="main">
    In main, not in any children
    <div class="child">one child</div>
    <div class="child">another child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it that what I need =)